# How do I open the dhcp-client log on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, event-log

Tried searching the web for answers but my google voodoo isn't strong enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dhcp-Client logs its events to the Windows Event Log.

To view this, open the [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-Event-Viewer), expand the Windows Logs entry on the left and select System. Here all system messages are shown.

To view only Dhcp-Client entries, click "Filter Current Log…" on the right.

In the dialog resulting from this, expand the Event sources drop-down list, and find and select "Dhcp-Client". You may want to select "DHCPv6-Client", too, but that depends on what you're trying to achieve.
[image: The filter interface]

Comment: On my computer there have been no new Dhcp-Client entries in the Windows System log for the last couple of weeks..  I enabled the log location given in the below answer; new entries have appeared there but not here.

Answer (score 2):

Windows DHCP client logs are available in Event Viewer.  Go to:

```
Event Viewer
  > Applications and Services Logs
    > Microsoft
      > Windows
        > Dhcp-Client
          > Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Client Events/Admin
```

If the log is empty, you may need to enable it first.  Go to "Dhcp-Client", select "Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Client Events/Admin", then click on "Properties" in the right hand pane.  Make sure the "Enable logging" option is checked.

Comment: That log is completely empty on my computer.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich You might need to enable it?

Go to:
    Event Viewer
      > Applications and Services Logs
        > Microsoft
          > Windows
            > Dhcp-Client.

Select "Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Client Events/Admin", then click on "Properties" in the right hand pane.  Is "Enable logging" checked?

Comment: your're right. Didn't know that these logs have to be enabled first.

Comment: Answer updated.